# OnCreate not called on Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

I've created `AbstractActivity` and an `AbstractFormActivity` to rid of some boilerplate code, their content may be irrelevant to the question, but I will post it anyway, maybe I misunterstood something so, there they are:

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected ObjectGraph graph;

    @Inject
    public Bus bus;

    @Inject
    public App app;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(getLayout());
        setupInjection();
    }

    public void setupInjection() {
        graph = ((App) getApplication()).createScopedGraph(getModule());
        graph.inject(this);
        bus.register(this);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
    }

    protected abstract Object getModule();
    protected abstract int getLayout();
}
```

and

```
public abstract class AbstractFormActivity<T extends EntidadeBase> extends AbstractActivity implements Form<T> {

    protected T entity;
    protected Map<View, Boolean> formValidations;
    protected AbstractFormActivity() {
       formValidations = new HashMap<View, Boolean>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    protected boolean passedValidations() {
        for (View key : formValidations.keySet()) {
            if (!formValidations.get(key)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void validateAndSolidify() {
        if (passedValidations()) {
            solidify();
        }
        entity = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void validateMoreComplexFields() {
    }
}
```

finally I've created an Implementation of those mother Activities:

```
public class MercadoriaFormActivity extends AbstractFormActivity<Mercadoria> {

...

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

...

}
```

My problem is that the `onCreate` method is not called.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`onCreate()` version you are currently using is added in Android 21. You should use version below instead:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: Helped a lot. Thank you for opening eyes :) I added onCreate in a fast manner and didn't notice I added the one from API 21. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same issue.
After a couple of hours, I found my mistake, instead on (savedInstanceState: Bundle, persistentState: PersistableBundle) function has to override the below one.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```